# cannot find implementation for com.application.unittest.data.local.ShoppingItemDatabase. ShoppingItemDatabase_Impl does not exist

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, android-room, junit4, android-testing

I have a problem with Room test I have checked all stackoverflow solutions, but nothing works for me.
I'm so beginner at test.
I tried a lot of solution like change kapt and add other libraries for room

This is the Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.application.unittest.data.local.ShoppingItemDatabase. ShoppingItemDatabase_Impl does not exist
at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:100)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:1486)
at com.application.unittest.data.local.ShoppingDaoTest.setup(ShoppingDaoTest.kt:40)
```

this is my DB class:

```
@Database(entities = [ShoppingItem::class], version = 1)
abstract class ShoppingItemDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun shoppingDao():ShoppingDao
}
```

This is the interface:

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertShoppingItem(shoppingItem: ShoppingItem)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteShoppingItem(shoppingItem: ShoppingItem)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_items")
    fun observeAllShoppingItems():LiveData<List<ShoppingItem>>

    @Query("SELECT SUM(price * amount) FROM shopping_items")
    fun observeTotalPrice():LiveData<Float>
}
```

This is the Test:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class ShoppingDaoTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var database: ShoppingItemDatabase
    private lateinit var dao: ShoppingDao

    @Before
    fun setup(){

            database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
                ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
                ShoppingItemDatabase::class.java
            )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
            dao = database.shoppingDao()

    }

    @After
    fun teardown(){
        database.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun insertShoppingItem() = runTest {
        val shoppingItem = ShoppingItem(id = 1,"name",1,2f,"image")
        dao.insertShoppingItem(shoppingItem)

        val allShoppingItems = dao.observeAllShoppingItems().getOrAwaitValue()

        assertThat(allShoppingItems).contains(shoppingItem)
    }

}
```

So what should I do?

UPDATE:

This is my dependencies. I guess maybe I missed something in my dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

//Material Design
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1"

//Architectural Component
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"

//Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.1"

//Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
kaptAndroidTest "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"


//Kotlin extension and Coroutines for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"

//Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"


//Coroutines
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1"

//Coroutines lifecycle scope
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.1"

//Navigation Component
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2"

//Glide
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0"

//Activity KTX for ViewModel
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"

//Dagger-Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

//Timber
implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//Local Unit Test
implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.1"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"
testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"

//Instrumentation Unit Test
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.1"
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an application class to instantiate the room database?

if so make sure your android manifest has this line of code under application.

<application
android:name="com.application.unittest.(then you application class name)"

Comment: No, I don't have that. I want to use TDD structure and Hilt. So I should build the Database in Hilt class and then instantiate the hilt class in Application class. So because it's base on TDD I didn't created yet. Should I at first create Application class and then Test the Database? Because of that I build the Database in setup function. So if it's not so, please tell me what should I write in Application class

Answer (score 0):

The app I built recently had the same error as yours but it worked after I put the application name in the manifest.  I was not using TDD or Hilt though so I am not sure if this will work or not.

But the application class I used contained this:

class MyApplication: Application() {

```
val database: your database class by lazy { your database class).getDatabase(this) }
```

}

Then make sure the application name is in the manifest. I hope this helps.

Comment: There is no getDatabase method in my Database class. Can you check this out? https://github.com/philipplackner/ShoppingListTestingYT/tree/TestingRoomDB   I don't know why it does work for him but not for me :( . I guess I didn't implement a library or something like this. Maybe I missed something so I update my post and add the dependencies