# How can to create a curved Text Button

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack

I'm beginner in jetpack compose, especially in Canvas.

I want to create this with Canvas:

[image]

But I don't know how.
I could create curved Text but with fillMaxSize and it's not useful for me. Because I want to use this picture as a button in a page and I have some buttons like this one in one page. So I want to have this Canvas with wrapcontent size.
So how can I create that?

Comment: No, I saw that. But I have same problem with that. I want to create a responsive page so I don't want to use dp and sp. and the other problem is turning around the text. Base on what it turns around? How can I use this near other Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer mentioned in the comments above is mine. I did some adjustments in order to give you some direction. The code is listed below:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ButtonWithCurvedText(
    @DrawableRes icon: Int,
    text: String,
    iconSize: Dp,
    onClick: () -> Unit, 
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val imgSize = iconSize
    val imageSizePx = with(density) { imgSize.toPx() }
    val labelSize = 12.sp
    val textToIconPadding = 4.dp
    val textToIconPaddingPx = with(density) { textToIconPadding.toPx() }
    val boxSize = imgSize + (textToIconPadding * 2) + with(density) { labelSize.roundToPx().toDp() }
    val boxSizePx = with(density) { boxSize.toPx() }

    val imageInset = ((boxSize - imgSize) / 2)
    val imageInsetPx = with(density) { imageInset.toPx() }

    val arcTop = imageInsetPx - (textToIconPaddingPx / 2f)
    val arcLeft = imageInsetPx - (textToIconPaddingPx / 2f)
    val arcBottom = boxSizePx - imageInsetPx + (textToIconPaddingPx / 2f)
    val arcRight = boxSizePx - imageInsetPx + (textToIconPaddingPx / 2f)

    val vectorPainter = rememberVectorPainter(
        ImageVector.vectorResource(icon)
    )
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(boxSize)
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .clickable {
                onClick()
            }
    ) {
        drawCircle(Color.LightGray, radius = imageSizePx / 2f)
        with(vectorPainter) {
            inset(
                horizontal = imageInsetPx,
                vertical = imageInsetPx
            ) {
                draw(Size(imageSizePx, imageSizePx))
            }
        }
        drawIntoCanvas {
            val path = Path().apply {
                addArc(arcLeft, arcTop, arcRight, arcBottom, 270f, 180f)
            }
            it.nativeCanvas.drawTextOnPath(
                text,
                path,
                0f,
                0f,
                Paint().apply {
                    textSize = labelSize.toPx()
                    textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

As you mentioned, you want something responsive. You just need to make some constants used here as parameters. The only "size" param required here is the icon size.
You can use like this:

```
Row() {
    ButtonWithCurvedText(R.drawable.ic_share, "Share", 48.dp, {})
    ButtonWithCurvedText(R.drawable.ic_cancel, "Cancel", 72.dp, {})
    ButtonWithCurvedText(R.drawable.ic_check, "Check", 96.dp, {})
}
```

The result is like below:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. That's wonderful. I have another  problem but no one answers me. this is the Stackoverflow's link : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670089/cannot-find-implementation-for-com-application-unittest-data-local-shoppingitemd) . please check it too and answer me, Thank you so much

Comment: How can I change text color?

Comment: You must set the `Paint` color. Inside of the `Paint().apply` block, call `color = Color.Blue.toArgb()`.